# Is there any method or something I can use to inspect and see is there any unused view files in project or just I can't find their usage?

Tags: laravel

My project is written with laravel 5.4
I use phpstorm 2021.3
There are some view files in resources folder that I can't find where they are used.
I tried to install a specific package for that purpose with this command

```
composer require typehints/laravel-unused
```

But the problem is. It can work for laravel version upper than 5.6.
So I got an error.
Then I tried the built-in function of phpstorm called "Inspect Code".
But there I didn't see any info about unused view files. I see what is not used in code of every file, but in my case I don't need to know about code, what variable or method is not used. I need  info about unused view files.

Comment: This is reason for which all apps should have tests. Create new git branch on project, remove view and run tests.

Comment: @CubeStorm thanks for an advice. I'll try it too. And. Is there any other solution? It will be good to have more than one possible solution.